# Animating HTML element position on DOM change

Tags: html, css

I have a list of tags that form a tag cloud. I'll include a search option that will hide/remove the tags that don't match the search. If I do this the tag cloud will rearrange automatically, but it will be instantaneously. I want some form of animation.

I've researched and discovered that the attribute `position` is not animatable. I've played around with MutationObserver and was able to detect changes in the DOM but was still unsure of what to do on the callback function.

```css
.tagcloud ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.tagcloud ul li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 .75em .5em 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.tagcloud ul li a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 padding: 0 1em;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 border-radius: 3px;
 word-wrap: normal;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: .2s;
 transition: .2s;
}
.tagcloud ul li span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: -10px;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 background-color: #3498db;
 border: 1px solid #3498db;
 border-radius: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: .2s;
 transition: .2s;
 -webkit-transform: scale(.4);
 transform: scale(.4);
}
.tagcloud ul li span::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: -8px;
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-top: -7px;
 border-color: transparent #3498db transparent transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 7px 14px 7px 0;
}
.tagcloud ul li a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #3498db;
 color: #3498db;
}
.tagcloud ul li:hover span {
 right: -26px;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tagcloud">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">javascript</a><span>10</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">android</a><span>6</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">c++</a><span>20</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a><span>15</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">java</a><span>16</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">html</a><span>4</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">css</a><span>11</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">python</a><span>17</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">artificial intelligence</a><span>5</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">computer graphics</a><span>9</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">php</a><span>8</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">computer audio</a><span>7</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">database</a><span>7</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">web</a><span>12</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">sql</a><span>6</span></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Using [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) with [left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) and [top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)?

Comment: @user7393973 Tried adding `transition: left 3s;` and `transition: top 3s;` to `.tagcloud ul li` and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/o8wx4bbz/) example.

Comment: @user7393973 I understand what you mean but I don't know where will the browser choose to move the remaining tags. I'm relying on the automatic re-positioning of the items but I want them to be animated.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question directly because in my opinion hiding element is a lot easier than remove it (or wait it removed).

After input event triggered, for each element we need to determine to do some animations or ignore it. In case of do animation we need to determine more between 2 animations which are exit animation (animate element then hide it) and entry animtion (show element then animate it).

```
input.addEventListener('input', event => {
  let re = new RegExp(input.value)

  ul.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
    let isHidden = li.style.display === 'none'
    let shouldHide = !re.test(li.textContent)

    if (shouldHide && !isHidden) {
      // Play exit animation
    }

    if (!shouldHide && isHidden) {
      // Play entry animation
    }
  })
})
```

I suggest to use javascript animation library (in example I use [animejs](http://animejs.com)) to handle animation instead of pure css animation because we need to toggle display which not working on pure css.

See full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rq4zbqh7/).

I hope this help. Thanks.

Comment: It looks far better than the default, but it's still not exactly what I want since I'm animating those who are removed and I want to animate those who remain and get re-positioned. But thank you, if I don't find an alternative I will use something along those lines ;)

Comment: You mean something like https://haltu.github.io/muuri or https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/ ?

Comment: Yes that's awesome